# removing hashtags from a string

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex:

```
preg_replace('/#(?=[\w-]+)/', '', preg_replace('/(?:#[\w-]+\s*)+$/', '', $stringText)
```

to basically replace/remove hashtags with empty string.

However it doesn't work for the following:

```
#jualbaju #blouse #jualmurah #bajumurah #jakarta #jualbajumurah #bajulucu #korea #dress #jualdress #murahmeriah #jualeceran #jualdressmurah #setelanmurah #jualsetelanmurah #bajupink #pink #jualshortdress #atasanmurah #bajukorea #bajukoreamurah #onlineshopindo #olshop #bajukoreamurah\n#jualbajukoreamurah #jualbajumurmer #dresskorea\n\nMinat hubungi cp di bio :) Line : shaneee22
```

Why is this?

Comment: How doesn't it work? What's the expected output?

Comment: @Jack it returns the whole string as is

Comment: The least it should do is remove the `#` characters; are you sure? Perhaps share the minimal code that reproduces your issue?

Comment: @adit: I believe you are not assigning result of `preg_replace` to a variable.

Answer (score 7):

This should work for you:

```
$re = '/#\w+\s*/';
$result = preg_replace($re, '', $input);
```

#### [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eX3nV4/2)

**EDIT:** Use this regex if you don't want to remove new line characters from your input:

```
$re = '/#\w+\h*/';
```

Comment: Looks good. However I think it shouldn't remove "new-lines". So it's better to use: `'/#\S+[ \t]*/'`

Comment: Sure if there are new lines to be skipped from this `'/#\S+[ \t]*/'` will be right regex.

Comment: Agree this works for the example string, but it is not perfect as `\S` matches ANY non-whitespace character. A hashtag can actually only include letters, number and underscores. Try `'/#[\w_]+[ \t]*/'` instead.

Comment: Few minor improvements in `'/#[\w_]+[ \t]*/'` `_` is already included in `\w` and `[ \t]` is same as `\h` (check edited answer)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~#[\w-]+~', '', $yourstring);
```

See the [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/27).

**Explanation**

- `#` matches the hash
- `[\w-]+` matches one or more word chars or hyphens
- we replace with the empty string

**What was wrong?**

- the first `preg_replace` didn't replace anything, because it couldn't find a series of hash tags followed by the end of the string (the `$` anchor)
- the second `preg_replace` only replaced the hashes, because what followed the hash was only a lookahead `(?=[\w-]+)`, which doesn't consume characters

Comment: FYI: Added explanation of what was wrong (as well and demo and explanation for fixed regex) :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you want to remove just the "#" or the name with it.

```
$string = "#jualbaju #blouse #jualmurah #bajumurah #jakarta #jualbajumurah #bajulucu #korea #dress #jualdress #murahmeriah #jualeceran #jualdressmurah #setelanmurah #jualsetelanmurah #bajupink #pink #jualshortdress #atasanmurah #bajukorea #bajukoreamurah #onlineshopindo #olshop #bajukoreamurah\n#jualbajukoreamurah #jualbajumurmer #dresskorea\n\nMinat hubungi cp di bio :) Line : shaneee22";

//Just the '#' removed
$noHashTag = str_replace('#', '', $string);

//The name too
$noHashTag = preg_replace('/#([\w-]+)/i', '', $string);
```

Comment: A few minor errors here: (1) A dash - is actually not allowed in a hashtag (2) Underscore _ is allowed in hashtag (3) No need for case-insensitive 'i' flag on your regex. I suggest `preg_replace('/#([\w_]+)/', '', $string);` instead

Answer (score -1):

I would like to way in to this topic. I tried first two option none of them worked, it return empty string. Below code works for me and i think it is much simpler.

```
$re = '/#*/';
$result = preg_replace($re, '', $input);
```

Comment: This only removes the hash. Not what the poster requires.